# Sorting input that get from file reading

Tags: arrays, file, sorting, arraylist

I am working on my homework and met some problem. I need to write a method that reads the file with double values  and takes a boolean value as parameter. If the boolean value is true, the method sorts the file in ascending order. If it is false, the file is sorted in descending order.

Here is what i accomplished:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Q2_2 {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File fw = new File("test.txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(fw);
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean b = scan.nextBoolean();

    ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();
    while(sc.hasNext()) {
       if(sc.hasNextDouble()) {
           list.add(sc.nextDouble());
       }
    }

    double[]result = new double[list.size()];
    for(int i=0; i<list.size();i++) {
        result[i]=list.get(i);
    }

    if(b == true) {
        for(int i=0; i<result.length;i++) {
            for(int j=i+1; j<result.length;j++) {
            if(result[i]>result[j]) {
                double temp = result[i];
                result[i]=result[i+1];
                result[i+1]=temp;
            }
            }
        }
    }else{
        for(int i=0; i<result.length;i++) {
            for(int j=i+1; j<result.length;j++) {
            if(result[i]<result[j]) {
                double temp = result[i];
                result[i]=result[i+1];
                result[i+1]=temp;
            }
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<result.length;i++) {
         System.out.println(result[i]);
    }   
}
```

}

I have prepare a text file for testing, but when I run the program and type in true/false, nothing happen. What I was trying to do is 
  first assign the read-in value in an ArrayList, cuz I don't know the   exact numbers of the input. 
  Second transfer the value in the arraylist into an array
  Third, sorting the array according to the input
  Forth, print out the array.

Comment: your sorting is wrong. that's not the cause of your problem though. the array "result" seems to be empty, otherwise you would get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException on the last iteration

Comment: Yes, i do get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. I don't understand why the array is empty though. Could you explain for me? thank you!

Comment: ah, well, if you get an exception, then it is not empty : ) you didn't specify that you get an exception in your question. if you want to get rid of that exception, you need to replace both of your loop conditions from `(int i=0; i<result.length; i++)` to `(int i=0; i<result.length-1; i++)`

Comment: I just get what ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException means lol. Thank you for pointing out for me! I think my sorting is still somehow wrong and i change it to  for(int i=0; i<result.length;i++) {
 for(int j=i+1; j<result.length;j++) {
   if(result[i]<result[j]) {
    double temp = result[i];
    result[i]=result[i+1];
    result[i+1]=temp;
    }
   }
  } But there still have no results, am i doing wrong with the printing?

Comment: there are many sorting algorithms out there, together with their implementations, try to check the web